# Error installing angular/cli using terminal

Tags: angular, npm, terminal

I'm trying to install angular/cli and when I run npm install -g @angular/cli in the terminal I come up with these error messages

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/katherine/npm-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue, and what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing administrator previllages.

if you are running on linux

try

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

if its on windows try to run command console as **administrator**

Answer (score 0):

try with sudo

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli